# pkg-config: Requires problem: ld cannot find file

Tags: gcc, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries, pkg-config

I have a library which until now was just a static library, and I used it as a submodule of my programs.

Now I want to be able to install it and be able to use it both as a static and a shared library.

I installed (apart from the header files) the following files:

```
$ tree /usr/local/lib/
/usr/local/lib/
├── libalx
│   ├── libalx-base.a
│   ├── libalx-base.so
│   ├── libalx-cv.a
│   ├── libalx-cv.so
│   ├── libalx-gsl.a
│   ├── libalx-gsl.so
│   ├── libalx-ncurses.a
│   ├── libalx-ncurses.so
│   ├── libalx-ocr.a
│   └── libalx-ocr.so
├── pkgconfig
│   ├── libalx-base.pc
│   ├── libalx-cv.pc
│   ├── libalx-gsl.pc
│   ├── libalx-ncurses.pc
│   └── libalx-ocr.pc
```

---

The contents of (some of) the pkg-config files are the following:

`libalx-base.pc`:

```
Name: libalx-base
Description: The libalx C/C++ library (base module)
URL: https://github.com/alejandro-colomar/libalx
Version: 1~b4
Requires: libbsd-overlay
Requires.private:

prefix=/usr/local/
libdir=${prefix}/lib/

Cflags: -D _GNU_SOURCE -D _POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L
Libs: -L ${libdir}/libalx/ -l alx-base
```

`libalx-cv.pc`:

```
Name: libalx-cv
Description: The libalx C/C++ library (openCV extension)
URL: https://github.com/alejandro-colomar/libalx
Version: 1~b4
Requires: libalx-gsl
Requires.private: opencv libalx-base

prefix=/usr/local/
libdir=${prefix}/lib/

Cflags: -D _GNU_SOURCE -D _POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L
Libs: -L ${libdir}/libalx/ -l alx-cv
```

`libalx-gsl.pc`:

```
Name: libalx-gsl
Description: The libalx C/C++ library (GSL extension)
URL: https://github.com/alejandro-colomar/libalx
Version: 1~b4
Requires:
Requires.private: gsl libalx-base

prefix=/usr/local/
libdir=${prefix}/lib/

Cflags: -D _GNU_SOURCE -D _POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L
Libs: -L ${libdir}/libalx/ -l alx-gsl
```

---

I'm using the library in a program that makes use of only two of the modules: base & cv.

I use the following `CFLAGS` and `LIBS` (LDFLAGS) in its Makefile:

```
################################################################################
# cflags
CFLAGS_STD      = -std=gnu17

CFLAGS_OPT      = -O3
CFLAGS_OPT     += -march=native
CFLAGS_OPT     += -flto

CFLAGS_W        = -Wall
CFLAGS_W       += -Wextra
CFLAGS_W       += -Wstrict-prototypes
CFLAGS_W       += -Werror

CFLAGS_PKG      = `pkg-config --cflags opencv`
CFLAGS_PKG     += `pkg-config --cflags libalx-cv`
CFLAGS_PKG     += `pkg-config --cflags libalx-base`

CFLAGS_D        = -D PROG_VERSION=\"$(PROGRAMVERSION)\"
CFLAGS_D       += -D INSTALL_SHARE_DIR=\"$(INSTALL_SHARE_DIR)\"
CFLAGS_D       += -D INSTALL_VAR_DIR=\"$(INSTALL_VAR_DIR)\"

CFLAGS          = $(CFLAGS_STD)
CFLAGS         += $(CFLAGS_OPT)
CFLAGS         += $(CFLAGS_W)
CFLAGS         += $(CFLAGS_PKG)
CFLAGS         += $(CFLAGS_D)

export  CFLAGS

################################################################################
# libs
LIBS_OPT        = -O3
LIBS_OPT       += -march=native
LIBS_OPT       += -flto
LIBS_OPT       += -fuse-linker-plugin

LIBS_PKG        = `pkg-config --libs libalx-cv`
LIBS_PKG       += `pkg-config --libs libalx-base`

LIBS            = $(LIBS_OPT)
LIBS           += $(LIBS_PKG)

export  LIBS

################################################################################
```

---

And I have the following error:

```
gcc tmp/coins.o tmp/main.o tmp/parse.o -o cv-coins  -O3 -march=native -flto -fuse-linker-plugin `pkg-config --libs libalx-cv` `pkg-config --libs libalx-base`
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/local//lib//libalx/: file format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

What is wrong?  I assume the problem is in the `.pc` files, but I tried moving dependencies from requires to requires.private, the other way around, and other things, and none worked.  For example, if I move `libbsd-overlay` to Requires.private, then the linker complains about not finding `strnstr`.

Comment: Is this `/usr/local//lib//libalx/` the problem?  i.e. you are using double forward slashes.  Should it be: `/usr/local/lib/libalx/`  ?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem.  I ignore if ld is special about it, but in POSIX double slashes are collapsed to a single one AFAIK.

Comment: Confirm it.  I mean you _are_ getting an `file format not recognized` error msg immediately after it sees that directory string.

Comment: Confirmed (for POSIX, `ld` should follow the rules): https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_266

Comment: Does removing the spaces after `-D`, `-L` and `-l` make any difference?

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes, it does, and I would like to know why. I think it's the answer, but is it my fault, or is it a bug in pkg-config (or gcc, or the linker)?  It works; you should post an answer.

Comment: I think it only matters for `-L`. The POSIX `c99` command allows a space after it, but I don't think `gcc` does.